# Single article separated into multiple pages makes Facebook Like button detect as completely separated articles

Tags: facebook, nextpage

I run a multiple author Wordpress platform where authors post articles where many of them are separated in several pages. The visitors can navigate the pages within the article by clicking on a `Next` button. This is various types of articles like galleries, lengthy articles, lists etc

I am sure you are all familiar with the Next button by now. The issue here is that the Facebook like button cannot detect that it is **one** article and treats it as completely separate pages.

This is the **valid** XHTML 1.0 code I use for the Like button:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode("http://domain.com" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=300&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border-style:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode("http://domain.com" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=300&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21" style="border-style:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:21px;">
</iframe>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

The IE conditions are there so that it works correctly in IE8.

The URL of the articles are like this. The original first page is:

```
http://domain.com/title-of-the-article/
```

And the second page is:

```
http://domain.com/title-of-the-article/2/
```

And so on... **How do I make it so that the Like button detects the second page as the first (original) page and avoid separating them as different**? I have tried hunting down a solution on Google without any direct results, someone mentioned to change `og:url` meta tag on the 'sub' pages to all point at the main URL for the article...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the 'like' URL. If you play with [the form FaceBook provides](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you can see how that works.

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

If you don't set the URL the default is the current URL, so you will have multiple pages.

So, and this is the only WordPress part of this question, use [`the_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) in that form.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```